# Build error while migrating gatsby from version 2 to 4

Tags: gatsby

I'm migrating my site from gatsby 2 to version 4. It runs perfectly with the `gatsby develop`. However, when I run `gatsby build`, I got the following error

```
Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: Channel closed
    at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:705:16)
    at onResult (/Users/h/Desktop/a/node_modules/gatsby-worker/dist/child.js:38:5)
Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
 {
  code: 'ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED'
}
/Users/h/Desktop/a/node_modules/yoga-layout-prebuilt/yoga-layout/build/Release/nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^

Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: Channel closed
    at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:705:16)
    at onResult (/Users/h/Desktop/a/node_modules/gatsby-worker/dist/child.js:38:5)
Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
 {
  code: 'ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED'
}
/Users/h/Desktop/a/node_modules/yoga-layout-prebuilt/yoga-layout/build/Release/nbind.js:53
        throw ex;
        ^

Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: Channel closed
    at process.target.send (internal/child_process.js:705:16)
    at onResult (/Users/h/Desktop/a/node_modules/gatsby-worker/dist/child.js:38:5)
Emitted 'error' event on process instance at:
 {
  code: 'ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED'
}
```

Do you know what this error means and possibly how to fix it?

For some reasons, the building time increases dramatically when I migrate my site to gatsby 4

```
Gatsby 2:  Done building in 182.340403886 sec
After upgrading to Gatsby 4: Done building in 385.763567997 sec
```

I also got these warning when building the site

```
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/ht/Desktop/a/gatsby-node.js' in '/Users/ht/Desktop/a'
<w> while resolving '/Users/ht/Desktop/a/gatsby-node.js' in /Users/ht/Desktop/a as file
⠏ Building Rendering Engines
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Serializing big strings (2076kiB) impacts deserialization performance (consider using Buffer instead and decode when needed)
```

Gatsby Info

```
 System:
    OS: macOS 11.3.1
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1038NG7 CPU @ 2.00GHz
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.15.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin/node
    npm: 6.14.8 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 97.0.4692.99
    Firefox: 96.0.2
    Safari: 14.1
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^4.5.2 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-background-image: 1.5.3 => 1.5.3
    gatsby-cli: ^3.1.0 => 3.14.2
    gatsby-plugin-emotion: ^7.6.0 => 7.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-feed: ^4.5.0 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager: ^4.5.0 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-image: ^2.5.2 => 2.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-lodash: ^5.5.0 => 5.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^4.5.2 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^5.5.0 => 5.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes: ^4.5.0 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-robots-txt: ^1.5.5 => 1.7.0
    gatsby-plugin-sentry: ^1.0.1 => 1.0.1
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^4.5.2 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-sitemap: ^5.5.0 => 5.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-typegen: ^2.2.4 => 2.2.4
    gatsby-plugin-typescript: ^4.5.2 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-remark-external-links: 0.0.4 => 0.0.4
    gatsby-source-contentful: ^7.3.2 => 7.4.0
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^4.5.2 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-source-workable: ^1.1.1 => 1.1.1
    gatsby-transformer-remark: ^5.5.2 => 5.6.0
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^4.5.0 => 4.6.0
```

=======================
If the build is successful, I have the cache version. If I build the site again without cleaning the cache, I got this error

```
Encountered an error trying to infer a GraphQL type for: `tagsList___NODE`. There is no corresponding node with the `id` field matching: "10d9531b-cc34-585e-a658-d2bb37977bef,520da789-a4c8-5465-af81-ae9e75d96123,c6c2bd79-1917-5fe8-848d-634c9ea702ce,d16915b0-7e55-5aca-9992-3d8
a780fe7ff,b4e89f32-400e-57a6-aa56-efe29657eae5,f7f9642e-b7c1-5c09-a08e-6bba3f96fa41,96c01237-f7cf-5f35-ad5c-0e05dfbc73cb,d90ffcca-762f-53bc-bd24-ee95402825e7,9d846575-611d-5f13-9002-7061fa697e24,08c8df32-e25b-5242-9f8a-3c429055d998,43475632-a0e5-5e24-a826-d01ce53ff7a4".



  Error: Invariant Violation: Encountered an error trying to infer a GraphQL type for: `tagsList___NODE`. There is no corresponding node with the `id` field matching: "10d9531b-cc34-585e-a658-d2bb37977bef,520da789-a4c8-5465-af81-ae9e75d96123,c6c2bd79-1917-5fe8-848d-634c9ea702
  ce,d16915b0-7e55-5aca-9992-3d8a780fe7ff,b4e89f32-400e-57a6-aa56-efe29657eae5,f7f9642e-b7c1-5c09-a08e-6bba3f96fa41,96c01237-f7cf-5f35-ad5c-0e05dfbc73cb,d90ffcca-762f-53bc-bd24-ee95402825e7,9d846575-611d-5f13-9002-7061fa697e24,08c8df32-e25b-5242-9f8a-3c429055d998,43475632-a0e
  5-5e24-a826-d01ce53ff7a4".
```

What is tagsList___NODE?
My Page content model in Contentful has a field called 'Tags list' which refers to the Tag model. It works perfectly with Gatsby version 2.
[image]

And I query the tagsList in the code

```
 const productsData = await graphql<any>(`
    query {
      allContentfulPageProduct(filter: { page: { elemMatch: { slug: { ne: null } } } }) {
        nodes {
          externalId
          page {
            slug
            tagsList {
              name
            }
          }
          blogSlugs
        }
      }
    }
  `);
```

Gatsby/gatsby-source-contentful automatically created a schema for me

```
    type ContentfulTag implements ContentfulReference & ContentfulEntry & Node @derivedTypes @dontInfer {
      contentful_id: String!
      node_locale: String!
      name: String
      page: [ContentfulPage] @link(by: "id", from: "page___NODE")
      spaceId: String
      createdAt: Date @dateformat
      updatedAt: Date @dateformat
      sys: ContentfulTagSys
    }

type ContentfulPage implements ContentfulReference & ContentfulEntry & Node @derivedTypes @dontInfer {
  contentful_id: String!
  node_locale: String!
  metaTitle: String
  slug: String
  content: ContentfulPageAboutContentfulPageBusinessValueCalculatorContentfulPageCareersContentfulPageCaseStudiesContentfulPageCloudContentfulPageClusterContentfulPageDevopsContentfulPageExpPostgresqlContentfulPageHomeContentfulPageIntegrationsContentfulPageNewsletterContentfulPageObservabilityContentfulPageOpenSourceContentfulPagePartnersContentfulPagePlansAndPricingContentfulPageProductContentfulPageSecurityAndComplianceContentfulPageSimpleContentContentfulPageSolutionContentfulPageSolutionType3ContentfulPageSolutionsContentfulPageSolutionsRetailContentfulPageTimeSeriesContentfulPageTimeSeriesChild1ContentfulPageTimeSeriesChildPage3ContentfulPageTimeSeriesChildPage4ContentfulPageTimeSeriesResourcesUnion @link(by: "id", from: "content___NODE")
  metaDescription: contentfulPageMetaDescriptionTextNode @link(by: "id", from: "metaDescription___NODE")
  spaceId: String
  createdAt: Date @dateformat
  updatedAt: Date @dateformat
  sys: ContentfulPageSys
  tagsList: [ContentfulTag] @link(by: "id", from: "tagsList___NODE")
}
```

Comment: So, the site is building isn't it?

Comment: @FerranBuireu After cleaning the cache, it builds successfully but the it takes 385.763567997sec to build (compared to only 182.340403886 sec with the Gatsby 2). It's quite weird

Comment: But when I run the build again without cleaning the cache. I always got the error 
Error [ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED]: Channel closed @FerranBuireu

Comment: Do you have `console.logs` across your `gatsby-node.js` or config files?

Comment: No, I've removed all the console.logs. I will debug it further and let you know if I found something weird. I guess the ERR_IPC_CHANNEL_CLOSED is due to an uncaught error somewhere

Comment: I know it's challenging for you to solve the issue since the info that I provided is not sufficient. However, if you see any error that is familiar to you then it may point me in the right direction. I updated the post. Thank so much @FerranBuireu

Comment: Indeed, it comes in pieces. What's,`tagsList__NODE`? Are you customizing the schema? If so... How?

Comment: @FerranBuireu I tried to delete all the code related to the tagsList. The error still happens. I guess that issue is related to the Contentful model?

Comment: It seems so. This will be tricky because we need to check how the nodes are inferred now in the changelog. Somewhere in your code you should filter for the `id` of the tag list, that seems to break the compilation

Comment: @FerranBuireu Hi, what do you mean by filtering for the id? Could you show me how I could check it in the changelog? I don't even know where to find the changelog

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I will take a further look at https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/34545

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging, the issue seems to be related to the Contentful source plugin (`gatsby-source-contentful`) according to some [GitHub threads](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/34545) and to the capability to create internal IDs for `tag` node (`tags___NODE`).

Aside of waiting the resolution you can try updating the plugin to the latest version.

Comment: Now my build always crashed when I fetching the hero image. Do you know why?
write EPROTO 4557528576:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

Comment: Can you open a new issue with the corresponding snippet? It will be easy to debug and see how's the GraphQL query there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926175/gatsby-4-error-with-eproto-when-querying-the-image-from-contentful 
Thank you