# Gatsby 4 error with EPROTO when querying the image from contentful

Tags: gatsby

whenever I run the build, I got the error with this image query. It worked perfectly with Gatsby 2.

I check the image and it's not large at all. Clean the cache does not help.

ERROR #85901  GRAPHQL

There was an error in your GraphQL query:

write EPROTO 4614737408:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

```
16 |         url
  17 |       }
  18 |     }
  19 |     backgroundPosition
  20 |   }
  21 |   description {
  22 |     description
  23 |   }
  24 |   heroImage {
  25 |     description
> 26 |     gatsbyImageData(width: 1500, layout: CONSTRAINED, placeholder: BLURRED)
     |     ^
  27 |   }
```

File path: /Users/ht/Desktop/a/website/src/templates/blog-post.tsx
Url path: /blog/introducing-for-postgresql
Plugin: none

My gastby info

```
System:
    OS: macOS 11.3.1
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1038NG7 CPU @ 2.00GHz
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.0.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/node
    npm: 7.10.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 97.0.4692.99
    Firefox: 96.0.2
    Safari: 14.1
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^4.6.0 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-background-image: 1.5.3 => 1.5.3
    gatsby-cli: ^4.6.0 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-image: ^3.11.0 => 3.11.0
    gatsby-plugin-emotion: ^7.6.0 => 7.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-feed: ^4.6.0 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager: ^4.6.0 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-image: ^2.5.2 => 2.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-lodash: ^5.6.0 => 5.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^4.6.0 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^5.6.0 => 5.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-remove-trailing-slashes: ^4.6.0 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-robots-txt: ^1.5.5 => 1.7.0
    gatsby-plugin-sentry: ^1.0.1 => 1.0.1
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^4.6.0 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-sitemap: ^5.6.0 => 5.6.0
    gatsby-plugin-typegen: ^2.2.4 => 2.2.4
    gatsby-plugin-typescript: ^4.6.0 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-remark-external-links: 0.0.4 => 0.0.4
    gatsby-source-contentful: ^7.4.0 => 7.4.0
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^4.6.0 => 4.6.0
    gatsby-source-workable: ^1.1.1 => 1.1.1
    gatsby-transformer-remark: ^5.6.0 => 5.6.0
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^4.6.0 => 4.6.0
```

I fetched image with gatsby-source-contentful. Defining the url in the gatsby-config.js

```
{
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-contentful',
      options: {
        spaceId: 'abc', // Main
        accessToken:
          process.env.CONTENTFUL_API_TYPE === 'preview'
            ? process.env.CONTENTFUL_PREVIEW_TOKEN
            : process.env.CONTENTFUL_DELIVERY_TOKEN,
        host: process.env.CONTENTFUL_API_TYPE === 'preview' ? 'preview.contentful.com' : 'cdn.contentful.com',
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-contentful',
      options: {
        spaceId: 'xyz', // Blog
        environment: 'master',
        accessToken:
          process.env.CONTENTFUL_API_TYPE === 'preview'
            ? process.env.CONTENTFUL_BLOG_PREVIEW_TOKEN
            : process.env.CONTENTFUL_BLOG_DELIVERY_TOKEN,
        host: process.env.CONTENTFUL_API_TYPE === 'preview' ? 'preview.contentful.com' : 'cdn.contentful.com',
      },
    }
```

Could you guys help me what the error means? Many thanks

Comment: Are you defining somewhere a URL for your domain or contentful space?

Comment: @FerranBuireu Updated the post, I only have the contentful space in the gatsby-config.js

Comment: @FerranBuireu The issue seems to be fixed if I add GATSBY_EXPERIMENTAL_QUERY_CONCURRENCY=8 to the .env file. Not sure how it helps but it fixed the issue? By default the GATSBY_EXPERIMENTAL_QUERY_CONCURRENCY=4, what number I should set here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be solved modifying the `GATSBY_EXPERIMENTAL_QUERY_CONCURRENCY` environment variable value, which by default is set to `4`.

This environment variable is the number of parallel GraphQL queries executed by Gatsby. In this case, from `4` to `8` does the trick.

The underlying issue (`EPROTO`) is likely to be a (timeout) server response due to the amount of data fetched and processed. Thanks to the increment of the concurrency, the issue is bypassed.

You can also try playing around with the `pageLimit` plugin configuration to check if the payload changes the behavior of the request.

Comment: Thank you. From the docs, we don't need to add the protocol to the host
https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/

Comment: Answer edited adding further explanation